# How to use React Native with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I've reading that React Native supports Typescript without dependencies like **react-native-typescript-transformer**. How do I configure it to code using **Typescript**?

Comment: Your title and description are a bit confusing, do you want to know how to add typescript or don't know how to use it? please elaborate.

Comment: I just edited it. Check it, please.

Comment: @IsaacFerreira is there any particular reason you don't want additional dependencies? Because one way or another you will need to add _some_.

Comment: Yes. If React Native has a built-in support to Typescript, I do not want to install unecessary dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Since 0.57.0

With the upgrade to Babel v7, Typescript is supported but you will still need to make some changes to your application:

- Install type definition dependencies `@types/jest @types/react @types/react-native @types/react-test-renderer`
- Change your `.js` files to `.ts` or `.tsx` depending on whether such files contain JSX or not. **Note**: keep `index.js` as is, otherwise Metro builder will fail since it is still not updated to expect a `.ts` entry file.
- You will need to add module declarations for binary assets like images, videos and json files for Typescript to understand how to import them (example [here](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/blob/master/template/images.d.ts)).
- For testing, Jest must be made aware of Typescript by adding the following to its configuration section in `package.json`:

  ```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$"
  }
  ```

Be aware that with this setup Babel just transforms Typescript to Javascript, it does not perform type-checking.

Also, expect possible issue since it is the first React Native release to support Typescript. My recommendation is to still follow the instructions below until things stabilize with time and patches.

#### Before 0.57.0

React Native does not offer first-party Typescript support. Instead, it offers [Flow](https://flow.org/) support out-of-the-box if you want types without having to add additional dependencies (other than `flow-bin` of course).

If you necessarily want Typescript, you will need to add some dependencies one way or another, depending on the setup you would eventually pick to use. There is a React Native blog post *[Using Typescript with React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/05/07/using-typescript-with-react-native)* that explains one way to add Typescript.

Comment: `Typescript is supported by default in 0.57. No transformers needed.` https://github.com/ds300/react-native-typescript-transformer/issues/77#issuecomment-421318966

Comment: Do you know how to get rid of it? I don't want to use Typescript. And just letting it be I get all types of linter errors.

Like with the `type Props = {};` I get the error:

>Typ aliases can only be used in TS Files

Comment: @GeraltDieSocke are you using Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Yes indeed. And it freaks out about typescript created from `react-native-cli`

Comment: The cli initiates a project that uses [Flow](https://flow.org) for static typing. You can either set `javascript.validate.enable` option to `false` in VS Code settings or take advantage of Flow, install the [Flow Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flowtype.flow-for-vscode) and follow its instructions.

Comment: @MateiRadu I wrote an updated blog post, since the one you linked is outdated. https://medium.com/@jan.hesters/using-typescript-with-react-native-946aa4b4ae6f